# CSS class helper (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use this module https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate

i try create new attribute when-visible-class="animated fadeInUp" but i get error 
Directive: angular-scroll-animate 'when-visible' attribute must specify a function.

Please see module https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate

jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/jgh9yumx/

Answer (score 0):

The error that you obtain is because the attribute when-visible isn't a function. You need only see the code of angular-scroll-animate:

```
if (!scope.whenVisible || !angular.isFunction(scope.whenVisible())) {
    throw new Error('Directive: angular-scroll-animate \'when-visible\' attribute must specify a function.');
}
```

If you want to pass a string use `'@'`, the `'&'` is only for functions.

In the next code extracted from the angular-scroll-animate, you can see that the whenVisible is a function.

```
scope: {
    whenVisible: '&',
    whenNotVisible: '&?',
    delayPercent: '=?',
    bindScrollTo: '@?'
}
```

Comment: i'm already use @ for new attribute  (whenVisibleClass: '@')  In my html i set  <div when-visible when-visible-class="fadeIn"></div>  and  i remove (!) in (if (scope.whenVisible || !angular.isFunction(scope.whenVisible())) ) but still showing error

Comment: In your html `<div when-visible when-visible-class="fadeIn"></div>` you need to set the `when-visible` attribute with a function and don't remove the `!`

Comment: but i was create new attribute whenVisibleClass: '@' and i set when-visible without function because it name directive please see jsfield jsfiddle.net/jgh9yumx/

Comment: But the `when-visible` attribute need the function mandatory. If you remove the function of `when-visible` attribute in your jsfiddle, you can see the same error..

Comment: Read the official notes of the directive: [angular-scroll-animate](https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate#notes) , the first point.